# Different img Sizes in Desktop and Mobile

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following table where I display a product image. In the desktop view I want to display the original size of the image and in the mobile version I want to display 180px and center it.

The code is as follows:

```
<h2><?php echo $product->product_name; ?></h2>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table">
        <tr><th></th><td ><img id="myImage" src="<?php echo CRM_URL; ?>img/product_images/<?php echo $product->product_image; ?>"  /></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Model Number</th><td><?php echo $product->product_model_number; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Category</th><td><?php echo $product->category; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Brand</th><td><?php echo $product->product_brand; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Price</th><td><?php echo $price; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo $cartForm; ?></td></tr>            
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS code:

```
@media(min-width: 320px) {
    .product_search_textbox {
        width: 100px;
    }
    #header div.topbar{
        height: 150px;
    }
    .homepage-slider-content{
        margin-top:18px;
    }

    #myImage { 
        width: 180px; 
    }  
}
```

I still can't get the image to change in the mobile view, could someone help me please? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it should be `(max-width: 320px)` because you want the mobile CSS to takeover when the width reduces below `320px`. Moreover, there has to be a `space` between `@media` and `(max-width: 320px)` like this:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .product_search_textbox {
        width: 100px;
    }
    #header div.topbar{
        height: 150px;
    }
   .homepage-slider-content{
    margin-top:18px;
    }

   #myImage { 
    width: 180px; 
    }  
}
```

Comment: it's not the space, because all the other css in that media query works fine. It's only the image width that doesn't work.

Comment: All the CSS added under the `media-query` for `min-width: 320px;` would only work if the width of the screen is greater than `320px`. On the other hand, all the CSS added under the `media-query` for `max-width: 320px;` would only work if the width of the screen is lesser than `320px`.

Comment: Can you share the link to the website where you're facing this problem? Also, try adding `!important` after the width like this: `#myImage { width: 180px !important; } `